# how to connect JProfiler with remote license server

Tags: linux, licensing, jprofiler

We just installed JProfiler on a Windows box and a Linux box.  The installs seemed to go fine.

We then installed the ejtlicense server on a different Linux box, and that seemed to go well also.

However, when we try to connect from the Windows or Linux box with JProfiler installed to the Linux license server, we get an error message saying that there was an error communicating with the license server.

Both systems can ping the hostname and the IP address of the license server.  I have checked the license server using the admin tool, and everything seems to be working correctly on the license server itself.

Is there a requirement to explicitly set up the port number, or will the default ports work correctly?

Thanks very much for any assistance anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, this is a firewall issue. On the license server, port 11862 has to be allowed for incoming connections.